# Control robot using keyboard in JAVA

Tags: java, nao-robot

I started to program a **NAO** Robot in IntelliJ IDEA and I am new in both, I created some functions that makes **NAO** to move or to speak, every time to see what is happening I have to run project. Now I want to execute some functions on KeyPress. Could you give me an example.

How to change this code, to allow **NAO** to Stand, Crouch or Sit on some KeyPress (ex: q-> Stand, w-> Crouch, e-> Sit)

```
 package test;

 import com.aldebaran.qi.Application;
 import com.aldebaran.qi.helper.proxies.ALMotion;
 import com.aldebaran.qi.helper.proxies.ALRobotPosture;
 import com.aldebaran.qi.helper.proxies.ALTextToSpeech;

 public class StandNao {

     private static ALMotion motion;

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         Application application = new NaoSettings().NaoConnect(args);



         application.start();
         motion = new ALMotion(application.session());
         // Create an ALTextToSpeech object and link it to your current session
         ALTextToSpeech tts = new ALTextToSpeech(application.session());
         // Make your robot say something
         tts.say("MAC Start Stand");
         motion.killAll();
         ALRobotPosture posture = new ALRobotPosture(application.session());
         posture.getPostureList();
         posture.goToPosture("Stand", 1.0f);

                 Thread.sleep(10000);

         posture.goToPosture("Crouch", 1.0f);

                 Thread.sleep(10000);

         posture.goToPosture("Sit", 1.0f);
     }
 }
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to write Java to control something as complex as a robot unless you know how to program in Java well.  Not a good "hello world" problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'll not describe all the possibilities over, but to give you a way to go, you can check many Java libraries who will let you manage poll or event driven keyboard input.

You can then make an infinite loop where you would listen to the keyboard activity, and react depending on the key hit.

It would barely looks like something like that:

```
Keyboard.poll();
while(Keyboard.next())  {

      if(Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_LEFT && !Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
             // do something if the letter left arrow key is released
      }

}
```

Also consider trying to make funny things, if you want to learn both Java and Web aspects, like a Web Application with REST controller, and when you hit buttons a web page, your robot move accordingly.

It can be quickly implemented by using [Java Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).